# why people still are using relational databases

Tags: nosql, rdbms

I'm learning about document based databases, and they seem perfect, so I ask why people are still using "classic" databases? why can't we move definitively to NoSQL?

Comment: Because they aren't perfect, far from it. Just check the hierarchical or network databases of the 70s, the object databases of the 90s,  and if you detect some similarities with document databases, you'll also find some of the disadvantages that make document databases not even close to ideal for generic use

Answer (score 5):

The answer is easy: There's still a lot of data that are represented *beautifully* by the relational model.

Relational databases separate the application and the data very well.  Having a declarative language like SQL, with a solid mathematical basis grounded in set theory, should not be thrown away lightly.

ACID means something significant.  Remind yourself next time you transfer funds between accounts.

Why should banks and other institutions throw away decades of investment?  What would the benefit be of using document-based databases?  That'd be a huge cost just to make a working application behave the same way using a new technology.  And what shiny new thing will you chase once that's done?

It's not either/or for SQL and NoSQL.  Both are just alternatives that have their place.

Answer (score 5):

1. Relational databases are around for 40 years now. They are a tried and true technology, and there is a lot of know-how around for them. They are an integral part of every computer science education and every programmer should have at least basic knowledge about how to use them. Document-oriented databases, on the other hand, are a rather new technology. There are few people around who can say that they ever completed a successful project with them, and even those people can't claim that they really know of all the pitfalls this new technology could have.
2. Most document-oriented databases have no native support for the thing relational databases call JOINs, so they have to be simulated on the application layer, which is uncomfortable and unperformant. JOINs can sometimes be avoided by denormalizing data, but denormalization turns ugly when you have aggregation instead of composition or n:m relations between entities.
3. Most document-oriented databases don't support transactions, at least none which span multiple documents. These aren't really required for many use-cases, but in sensitive areas (like many which deal with money) you just can't do without. There are workarounds (like the two-phase commit), but these are hard to program (and thus bug-prone) and slow.
4. A schemaless database can be a blessing due to its flexibility, but it can quickly turn into a curse. Thanks to a well-defined schema with constraints and triggers, a relational database can be made smart enough to reject any data which just doesn't make sense. A schemaless database, on the other hand, will happily accept any garbage-data it is fed by a buggy client.

I don't want to badmouth document-oriented databases. I use one for one of my own projects, and I don't regret the decision. But you always need to pick the right tool for every job. Sometimes it's a relational database, sometimes it's a document database, sometimes it's a graph database and sometimes it's just good old flatfiles.